# Where is ChromeDriver in .NET?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have references to

- nunit.framework
- WebDriver
- WebDriver.Support

I have downloaded ChromDriver.exe, put it in a directory, and included that directory in System Variables > Path. But I don't see the actual class in intellisense.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to include,

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
```

[This](http://www.joecolantonio.com/2013/01/18/selenium-webdriver-using-chrome-webdriver-in-visual-studio-c/) link might be helpful, though for VS